# Merge (fuse) two meshes together

Tags: modeling

I want to merge the pipe and the bottom part together so it looks like the pipe is welded to it. I tried merging using ALT + M but the result is not good. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[image]

Comment: What you need is Boolean.  Boolean merges 2 mesh together geometrically.  The blending profile between the merge is a bit harder to achieve if you don't know how to do it manually.  But it isn't too hard when you understand how, it just take lots of time.

Comment: "First off, ask yourself if you really need those two pipes connected?" - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27386/2217 and [How to create proper displacement for weld joints?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15628/2217)

Comment: Is the weld being shown in closeup detail or does it distance faint impressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create Hole. Mesh LoopTools Addon. Extrude and Shape.**

[image]

- Simplified Shapes.  A Box representing your lantern.
- Suggestion change your mesh model construction technique as indicated below.
- Faces Removed. Counting edges to match a destination shape.  Appropriate vertex density.
- Square hole shaped to circular with LoopTools Circle.
- Extruded.  Shaped with Proportional Edit. We see a continous well shaped extrusion rather than two meshes islands intersecting.
- Now you can align the base with the two (side supports) to create a continuous surface.  You can use Bridge Edge Loops for that.  This is not shown but is certainly shown here at BSE on other questions.
- Weld Pattern Options

  - Torus modified with Proportional Edit / Displacement Textures as an optional separate Mesh.
  - Higher (localized) vertex density for weld patterns
  - Texture paint
  - Not Recommended Particle System unless Spheres

Answer (score 1):

**Clip-On Weld**

[image]

If your case allows, you might add a modified torus with appropriate vertex density.

- The single crease is proportional edit.
- The more bumpy area is a Displace Modifier.
- The Torus is a separate object above and covers the joint area.  Just like some you would see at a hardware store.

---

[image]

---

- You can improve and spend more time to be more Artistic.
- No effort or time was taken in the image above to be Artistic.

Answer (score 0):

Used a Boolean modifier on the tube with the Union operation to fuse it to the bottom part

Comment: This only works if both are separate objects, which doesn't appear to be the case. It will also invariably leave bad topology.

Comment: They are separate objects, and that actual lantern will not be seen from a few meters away so it won't be apparent