# Welded Iron bronze/silver material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Ive made an exhaust manifold with welds in cycles, Im trying to acheieve a realistic material where the welds are a rusted bronze like in the image attached. How would I go about getting this result?

[image]

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/how-to-create-proper-displacement-for-weld-joints

Comment: Theres nothing about materials, Just how to create the welds which I have done.

Comment: Nice model. Your materials question is a pretty broad one though. I'd suggest you do some research into applying materials. You might start with Blender Guru's Principled Shader video (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blender+guru+principled&t=ffab&atb=v100-1&ia=videos).

Comment: look into using a mixture of different materials and control the mix using pointiness and a ramp. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyCe4BFQ8eg